# Durable Task Framework re-queue failed task

Tags: azure, azure-storage

How to use "waiting for external" event functionality of durable task framework in the code. Following is a sample code.

```
context.ScheduleWithRetry<LicenseActivityResponse>(
                typeof(LicensesCreatorActivity),
                _retryOptions,
                input);
```

I am using ScheduleWithRetry<> method of context for scheduling my task on DTF but when there is an exception occurring in the code. The above method retries for the **_retryOptions** number of times.

After completing the retries, the Orchestration status will be marked as **Failed**.

I need a process by which i can resume my orchestration on DTF after correcting the reason of exception.

I am looking into the githib code for the concerned method in the code but no success.

I have concluded two solution:

1. Call a framework's method (if exist) and re-queue the orchestration from the state where it failed.
2. Hold the orchestration code in try catch and in catch section i implement a method **CreateOrchestrationInstanceWithRaisedEventAsync** whcih will put the orchestration in hold state until an external event triggers it back. Whenever a user (using some front end application) will call the external event for resuming (which means the user have made the corrections which were causing exception).

These are my understandings, if one of the above is possible then kindly guide me through some technical suggestions. otherwise find me a correct path for this task.

Comment: Salman, Could you provide the context of the issue? Is this happening when using Azure storage SDK to upload something ? the context would help us provide an accurate answer.

Comment: Hello @AdamSmith-MSFT, i am talking about durable task framework (https://github.com/Azure/durabletask) which runs the orchestrations using the user defined activites in c# code. I have somehow solved the problem by creating a sub orchestration in case of an exception occurs while performing an activity. The sub orchestration lock the event on azure as pending state and wait for an external event which raise the locked event so that the parent orchestration resumes the process on activity. This process helps if our orchestrations is about to fail on azure durable task framework.

Comment: I hope i was able to explain the problem and the solution well enough :)

Comment: Awesome Salman, thanks for the explanation, btw, you could propose your solution in the answer field so it would be useful to the community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the solution for my problem by using "Signal Orchestrations" taken from [code from GitHub repository](https://github.com/Azure/durabletask).

Following is the solution diagram for the problem.

[image]

In this diagram, before the solution implemented, we only had "Process Activity" which actually executes the activity.

**Azure Storage Table** is for storing the multiplier values of an instanceId and ActivityName. Why we implemented this will get clear later.

**Monitoring Website** is the platform from where a user can re-queue/retry the orchestration activity to perform.

Now we have a pre-step and a post-step.

**1. Get Retry Option** (Pre-Step)
This method basically set the value of **RetryOptions** instance value.

```
private RetryOptions ModifyMaxRetires(OrchestrationContext context, string activityName)
    {
        var failedInstance =
            _azureStorageFailedOrchestrationTasks.GetSingleEntity(context.OrchestrationInstance.InstanceId,
                activityName);

        var configuration = Container.GetInstance<IConfigurationManager>();

        if (failedInstance.Result == null)
        {
            return new RetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(configuration.OrderTaskFailureWaitInSeconds),
                    configuration.OrderTaskMaxRetries);
        }

        var multiplier = ((FailedOrchestrationEntity)failedInstance.Result).Multiplier;

        return new RetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(configuration.OrderTaskFailureWaitInSeconds),
                configuration.OrderTaskMaxRetries * multiplier);
    }
```

If we have any entry in our azure storage table against the **instanceId** and **ActivityName**, we takes the multiplier value from the table and updates the value of retry number in **RetryOption** instance creation. otherwise we are using the default number of retry value which is coming from our config.

**Then:**
We process the activity with scheduled retry number (if activity fails in any case).

**2. Handle Exceptions** (Post-Step)
This method basically handles the exception in case of the activity fails to complete even after the number of retry count set for the activity in **RetryOption** instance.

```
private async Task HandleExceptionForSignal(OrchestrationContext context, Exception exception, string activityName)
    {
        var failedInstance = _azureStorageFailedOrchestrationTasks.GetSingleEntity(context.OrchestrationInstance.InstanceId, activityName);

        if (failedInstance.Result != null)
        {
            _azureStorageFailedOrchestrationTasks.UpdateSingleEntity(context.OrchestrationInstance.InstanceId, activityName, ((FailedOrchestrationEntity)failedInstance.Result).Multiplier + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            //const multiplier when first time exception occurs.
            const int multiplier = 2;

            _azureStorageFailedOrchestrationTasks.InsertActivity(new FailedOrchestrationEntity(context.OrchestrationInstance.InstanceId, activityName)
            {
                Multiplier = multiplier
            });
        }

        var exceptionInput = new OrderExceptionContext
        {
            Exception = exception.ToString(),
            Message = exception.Message
        };

        await context.CreateSubOrchestrationInstance<string>(typeof(ProcessFailedOrderOrchestration), $"{context.OrchestrationInstance.InstanceId}_{Guid.NewGuid()}", exceptionInput);
    }
```

The above code first try to find the instanceID and ActivityName in azure storage. If it is not there then we simply add a new row in azure storage table for the InstanceId and ActivityName with the default multiplier value 2.

Later on we creates a new exception type instance for sending the exception message and details to sub-orchestration (which will be shown on monitoring website to a user). The sub-orchestration waits for the external event fired from a user against the InstanceId of the sub-orchestration.

Whenever it is fired from monitoring website, the sub-orchestration will end up and go back to start parent orchestration once again. But this time, when the Pre-Step activity will be called once again it will find the entry in azure storage table with a multiplier. Which means the retry options will get updated after multiplying it with default retry options.

So by this way, we can continue our orchestrations and prevent them from failing.

Following is the class of sub-orchestrations.

```
internal class ProcessFailedOrderOrchestration : TaskOrchestration<string, OrderExceptionContext>
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<string> _resumeHandle;

    public override async Task<string> RunTask(OrchestrationContext context, OrderExceptionContext input)
    {
        await WaitForSignal();
        return "Completed";
    }

    private async Task<string> WaitForSignal()
    {
        _resumeHandle = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        var data = await _resumeHandle.Task;
        _resumeHandle = null;
        return data;
    }

    public override void OnEvent(OrchestrationContext context, string name, string input)
    {
        _resumeHandle?.SetResult(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the community's benefit, Salman resolved the issue by doing the following:

> "I solved the problem by creating a sub orchestration in case of an exception occurs while performing an activity. The sub orchestration lock the event on azure as pending state and wait for an external event which raise the locked event so that the parent orchestration resumes the process on activity. This process helps if our orchestrations is about to fail on azure durable task framework"

Comment: I am busy in finalizing the solution by testing and applying patterns for better solution. I will answer to this in up coming days with full and test solution.